# How to specify the name of uploaded to using REST API with uploadType=Media

Tags: c++, rest, google-drive-api

I am using REST API to upload a file to the google drive. I know the name of the file to upload to and its id.

On the request URL line I was not able to find a way to specify the receiving file name or Id.
Post https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media
Is there any way to set the name or fileId of the file in the request header?
Thank you

Comment: It seems to specify metadata about the file, you need to make a multipart POST request that contains both metadata and content.  Check out the example here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#uploading_using_a_pregenerated_id

Comment: Thank you. I did use the multi part Post request, Every time I have an error message: Error  QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ContentNotFoundError). I filled in therequest header with the length of the request body. I appreciate any help

Comment: can you post a code snippet?